# How to get cell number in excel by providing cell content using java POI 3.8?

Tags: java, excel

I need to get the cell index of particular string in excel using java code.
e.g if the cell(23,1) contains the string 'Student_address', the method have to get the return as 'cell index'

System.out.println(sheet.getRow(1).getCell(23) will print the value of student_id in corresponding row-1.
Here sheet is the excel worksheet.

I just want to get the 23 dynamically by giving cellContent as 'Student_id'.I need the colomn number in excel exactly.
Please help me out to get cell index by considering java poi 3.8 version.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to search for the value cell by cell in a loop.

Comment: I have used the code taken from stackExcahnge                       for(Row row : sheet) {
            for(Cell cell : row) {

                while(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){

                    if(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString () == cellContent);{rowNum = row.getRowNum();
                            return rowNum;  
                }        }
        }                                                           It doesnt give me the colomn instead it is giving me the rowNum as 0.How can I make it as colomn? thank you for the reply.